# Error while creating a new activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

Every time I create a new activity in Android Studio, I get an error like this:

```
Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
           Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 17,4,main] 1345722054;
           dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
           SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.3#AI-141.2178183, eap:false,6,main] 2033877427
```

It doesn't cause any problem though, and the activity is created like it should normally be. So what is the problem?

Comment: is this complete log?

Comment: Yeah that's all that shows use in the event log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no evidence that this log is related to your application.
it has something to do with android studio (intellij) which you can easily ignore as long as everything is working fine for you.

Comment: Yeah it's an IDE internal error, I just don't want it tampering with my project, that's all.

Comment: don't worry you are fine with it :)